# How to find text from an image and identify it's coordinated using karate UI and karate Robor

Tags: karate

I want to highlight a window and  find the text in an image and also get its coordinates. How can we do this through karate UI and karate robot.

Comment: there is no easy answer to your question. you have to read the documentation and try. also please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This question has not come up before, so it will require some research. I will try to provide some hints below, but this may require someone with knowledge of Java and the Windows API to figure out.

First, refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-robot

Behind the scenes, Karate Robot is using the Windows API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32

And refer the `Element` implementation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.3.1/karate-robot/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/robot/win/WinElement.java

If I remember correctly, you should be able to call `element.property('')` and get the values you want.

Here is the reference for all properties: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.3.1/karate-robot/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/robot/win/Property.java

So maybe this will work (I have not tried):

```
* def e = locate('locator')
* def rect = e.property(30001)
```

Which I think will get you this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationcore/ns-uiautomationcore-uiarect

I am not sure how to get the values out, maybe `rect.left` etc. will work, or it may be a JSON. It will be great if you or your team can contribute if needed to the code and documentation.